# Logging to mysql server from a remote host

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble executing the command

`grant select, insert, delete, update
on dbname.*
to username identified by 'password';`

from my remote connection to my server. It responds with

`ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'xxx.xxx.x.xx1' to database 'dbname'`.

My server's address is `xxx.xxx.x.xx1` and my remote machine's address is `xxx.xxx.x.xx2`.

I login to the MySQL server from my remote machine using the command

`sudo mysql -h xxx.xxx.x.xx1 -u root -p`

When I run the command `select current_user()` from my remote connection, it returns `root@'xxx.xxx.x.xx1'`. Shouldn't it return `root@xxx.xxx.x.xx2'`?

I added all privileges to `root@'xxx.xxx.x.xx1`' and `root@'xxx.xxx.x.xx2'`.

Why can't I execute the command from my remote machine when I have given access to root for my remote connection's ip address? Is `select current_user()` supposed to return my remote machine's ip address or my server's when logged in from the remote machine?

Comment: It should return the remote machine's address. Is it possible you have a proxy intercepting the connection and going through a tunnel?

Comment: Just as a word of caution, you really shouldn't be using your `root` user account remotely at all.  You are passing your root user password around in the clear.

Comment: @Barmar: I don't believe that I am going through a proxy.

Comment: Are you using SSL? Check root's `my.cnf` file for `ssl-XXX` options. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029954/connecting-to-mysql-using-ssl#14029954 for another case where the server reports the connection coming from its own IP instead of the client.

Comment: I checked the my.cnf file and the ssl-XXX options were commented out. Also, I executed `mysql>show variables like "%ssl%";` and the results showed
`have_openssl DISABLED`
`have_ssl DISABLED`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

First, I changed the bind address line in /etc/mysql/my.cnf from 127.0.0.1 to my server's address.

Second, I logged in as root into mysql locally on my server and created another user with this command:

`grant select, insert, update, delete on databasename.* to newuser@my_remote_desktop_address identified by 'password';`

I could then log into mysql on my desktop under the new user and execute my commands.